# Jsoup (connect) Java takes a long time

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get a few lines of code from many html pages.

I'm using Jsoup and it takes over 2 minutes to go over 70+ html pages (90% of the time is spent on creating the new Document through jsoup.connect).

Is this normal? Would using another parser make any difference?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Url).timeout(10*1000).get();
```

I'm able to go through all the webpages.

Comment: Do you have detailed statistics, maybe only one of the 70+ pages is slow or not available at all? The `Connection` returned by `connect` is not yet the document. You should provide some code?!

Answer (score 0):

The jsoup normally takes about 2 seconds to make connetion and to fetch html content

In case if the url is redirected to another site,then it may take up to 5 seconds.

May be some of the pages which you fetch may be redirected,set the timeout to 3 seconds ,you may know what went wrong ..